# collision resistance of a composed hash function

Tags: hash, collision-resistance, stream-cipher

Given a collision-resistant hash function $H(x)$, say SHA256, and I devise another hash function by $H'(x)=\sum^{m}_{1}H(x||i) \mod p$. The summation is defined on finite field of prime order $p$.

Is the new hash function $H'(x)$ still collision resistant? How hard is it to find a collision? Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I don't think there's anything that can be said without stronger assumptions on $H$ than just collision resistance. In particular, even for $m=2$, it's easy to construct artificial $H$ (by tweaking an existing collision-resistant hash for a few inputs) that are collision resistant, but for which $H'$ has trivial collisions.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen: I believe that's the answer: "$H'$ is not necessarily collision resistant because (assuming there exists *a* collision resistant hash function) we can devise an $H$ which is collision resistant, but $H'$ is not".  Trivial example: assuming $H^*$ is a collision resistant hash function, define $H(x) = p \times H^*(x)$...

Comment: Or, are you asking "if we assume a random (or not deliberately malformed) $H$, how difficult would this be?"

Comment: @poncho, sorry for this very late reply. In my case, we could just assume $H$ to be sha256. Then how hard the $H'$ can be?

Answer (score 2):

Counterexample [from poncho in comments]: let $H_0\colon \{0,1\}^* \to \{0,1\}^{256}$; then $H(x) := p \cdot H_0(x)$, where $H_0(x)$ is interpreted as an integer in little-endian, is obviously collision-resistant but $H'(x) := \sum H(\cdots) \bmod p$ is identically zero and therefore very much not collision-resistant no matter what goes in the ellipsis.